# In a Riesz space, does $(u+v)^+=u^+ + v^+$ hold?

Tags: vector-lattices

Assume that $E$ is a Riesz space (lattice ordered vector space). For $u\in E$, let $u^+ = u\vee 0$.

Then, for $u,v\in E$, does $(u+v)^+=u^+ + v^+$ hold?

Comment: That isn't even true on $\mathbb R$. Take $u = 1$ and $v=-1$.

Comment: Then is there any relationship between $(u+v)^+$ and $u^+,v^+$?

Comment: on the reals $\le$. On a Riesz space, I am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you will only have $(u+v)^+ \le u^+ + v^+$ and this is easy to prove.